# Uniform template deduction across multiple arguments

Tags: templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I'd like to see if it is possible (though I have a feeling it is not) whether it is possible to apply uniform types based on the first template argument given. For example:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T, T) {}

int main() {
  // deduced as int
  foo(1, 1);

  // deduced as double
  foo(1.0, 1.0);

  // not deducible, will error.
  //foo(1.0, 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Is there some technique which will allow me to force the second parameter of foo to be exactly the first? I do realize that the canonical solution, albeit slightly more verbose would be `foo<double>(1.0, 1)`.

That being said I'd like to be able to execute `foo(1.0, 1)` which would force the second parameter type as the first, and upcast 1 to 1.0.

Additionally, `foo(1, 1.0)` would fail because the first parameter sets `foo` to `foo<int>`, and as such the second parameter could not be downcast to an int.

Finally, I'd like to be able to do this without recursive templatization, as I'd like to apply this technique to object constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make uses of the template parameter in function parameters after the first into "non-deducible contexts":

```
template <typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T>
using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;

template <class T>
void foo(T, type_identity_t<T>) {}
```

Now `foo(1.0, 1)` means the same as `foo<double>(1.0, 1)`, and the function specialization has arguments `(double, double)` so the `1` is implicitly converted from `int` to `double`.  And the other way around, `foo(1, 1.0)` means `foo<int>(1, 1.0)` and the `1.0` is implicitly converted to `int`.

(Note [`std::type_identity_t` is coming in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity).)

Comment: Beautiful. I am curious though if there is a way to make `foo(1, 1.0)` fail. The current solution is better in fact since it can work both ways, but I am still curious.

Comment: Fail based on what? Both int to double and double to int are allowed standard conversions, and both are normally narrowing conversions.

Comment: doh. sorry for some reason I thought double to int required an explicit downcast.